# Wordpress | Content area does not automatically expand

Tags: css, wordpress

my Wordpress theme is not expanding its content area as I enlarge, for example, the comment box, so the whole content goes over the footer. The footer remains fixed at the bottom of the page, but does not push itself down when I expand the comment box...

I tried reading other questions, but I've not fixed that problem.

The code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/mh3gHSVJ

Thanks for your competence and support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without trawling through all of your CSS code it's quite difficult to tell. You should only post the relevant code, also try and supply a 'live' example of the page.

It sounds to me like you need to use `display:block` and `overflow:hidden` on the parent of the comment box. Make sure there is no height element given to it, or if there is make it `height:auto`.